# Instagram API cursor loop

Tags: cursor, instagram

I'm doing some searching using the Instagram REST API. Specifically, the endpoint I'm using is /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. I'm first getting the number of media items with the tag in question using /tags/{tag-name}, which is ~445K. I'm going through all the media items using the 'next_max_tag_id' that comes along with the response. I don't know how long this takes, but at some point, the max IDs start to loop. Not back to back, but as of ~250K, it's just constantly looping over the same 5 next_max_tag_id values.

1. Am I doing it wrong by counting the number of items I've processed and comparing it to the number of media items I'd previously gotten?
2. How do you know when you've reached the end of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the answer here:

[Instagram realtime get post from callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459151/instagram-realtime-get-post-from-callback/21606348#21606348)

I think this scenario is the same as yours.